# Use IF condition inside a function that defines a hook

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am new to PHP. I am trying to use an IF condition inside a function. The function originally contains a hook which works well without the IF condition, but I need the IF condition to display this hook to only site visitors who are not logged in.

What is wrong with my code, please?

I have been able to display the function in a template without any problems. But the function is supposed to be displayed to only logged out users, and I have tried adding an IF condition to achieve this, all to no avail.

```
function add_signup_notice_after_excerpt_two() 
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '//Some HTML'
    }; 
    else{
    };

    add_action( 'signup_notice_after_excerpt_two', 'add_signup_notice_after_excerpt_two', 5 );
}
```

I expected the hook to display the HTML code in the IF condition when used in the template, but it did not display. However, the hook worked in the template without the condition.

Comment: Hint: indent by 4 spaces for a code block on the SO editor ;)

Comment: @CD001 Or you can use three backticks on the line before and after your codeblock! ;-)

Comment: @Qirel ... I did not know that! :D ... normally I just dump it into a text editor and [tab] it.

Comment: You shouldn't have a semi-colon on the else - might be causing the issue

Comment: the semi-colon on the echo line should be swapped with the ending curly brace - this will cause a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function add_signup_notice_after_excerpt_two() 
{
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Some HTML'; } 
    else{

    }
}

add_action('wp','add_signup_notice_after_excerpt_two', 5 );
```

The bug was, You have created a function but you did not Hook `add_signup_notice_after_excerpt_two()` on to a specific `action` and that  `add_action()` must be out side the function in your case.
And there had some syntax errors in your code.

Go through the following link.

How to add an actoin :https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Different kinds of action hooks:https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Your code solved the problem. Thanks for saving me from several hours of trying to fix it. However, the HTML code in the echo line was injected in the header, above all other content for logged out users, so I replaced it with a unique argument which was probably not being referenced elsewhere. But I wonder why the original argument didn't work. I am quite new to PHP.

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check it. If my answer helped you then accept it. Thank you @Cliff

Comment: Yes, it helped me. Thank you